# Pass parameters to next steps in clickfunnels

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I need to populate several forms in several steps after the clickfunnel contact form. I was willing to pass them in the URL as parameters but for some reason clickfunnels seems to strip out parameters from the URL (or just as likely, I am not encoding the parameter correctly)

a. How do you pass the contact fields as parameters in the redirect URL (or an this be done)
b. If not then what code would I use and where in clickfunnels would I place it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I capture the value of the input field on form submit and store it in localStorage, then you can get it from local Storage on the next page and populate into the value of the form on the next page.